# Table In XAml Windows Store App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

### My TABLE code

ItemS Control Working Perfectly But I need only one listview inside listview help i get problem in

### c Get Set Class I need a Single List

Hi I Need To Generate A Table In My Metro APP BUT I GET WRONG OUTPUT PLEASE HELP I BIND HEADER AND CONTENTS SEPERATELY USING LIST

C# CODE

```
 foreach (var item in itemsreceiveds)
        {
            variable2.Add(new contentdata() { firstdata = item.getFirstData, seconddata = item.getSecondData, thirddata = item.getThirdData, headers = item.getFieldName });
        }
        var groupedPersons = variable2.Select((emp) => new { sectionName = emp.headers }).ToList().Distinct();
         foreach (var s in groupedPersons)
         {
             firstheader = s.sectionName;
             string[] sepword = firstheader.Split('#');
             firstheader = sepword[0].ToUpper();
             secondheader = sepword[1].ToUpper();
             thirdheader = sepword[2].ToUpper();  
             variableheader.Add(new contentdataheader(firstheader,secondheader,thirdheader));
             groupListView.ItemsSource = variableheader;
         }
         //SUBITEM
          foreach (var person in variable2)
         {
             subdata.Add(new subitems(person.firstdata, person.seconddata, person.thirddata));
         }
         itemListViewss.ItemsSource = subdata;
```

XAML

```
        <ListView Name="groupListView" CanDragItems="True" CanReorderItems="True" AllowDrop="True" IsSwipeEnabled="True" SelectionMode="None" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="0">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <Border x:Name="bordermenu" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Width="150">
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding Firstheader}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                    <Border x:Name="bordermenu2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Width="150">
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding Secondheader}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                    <Border x:Name="bordermenu3" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Width="150">
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding Thirdheader}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <ListView Name="itemListViewss" CanDragItems="True" CanReorderItems="True" AllowDrop="True" IsSwipeEnabled="True" SelectionMode="None" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <Border x:Name="bordersubmenu" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Width="150">
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Blue" Text="{Binding dynamic}" x:Name="submenu" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"   />
                    </Border>
                    <Border x:Name="bordersubmenu2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Width="150">
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Blue" Text="{Binding p1}" x:Name="submenu2"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
                    </Border>
                    <Border x:Name="bordersubmenu3" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Width="150">
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Blue" Text="{Binding p2}" x:Name="submenu3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
                    </Border>                        
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

**I Get Ouput As**

[image: I Get Ouput As]

**But I Need Output As This**

[image: But I Need Output As This]

Comment: If you have a telerik license they have a nifty DataGrid for it, http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-8/controls-xaml/grid.aspx

Comment: It is considered polite to mark the correct answer.

Answer (score 22):

Here's the simplest answer - a working demo.

I didn't do everything for you, mate, but I sure did a lot. You'll have to code a little to get it just how you like. If you are using a custom control suite, most of this might be done for you. If not, this will get you down the road. Far down the road.

Take this code behind:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public class Datum
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Year { get { return Date.ToString("yyy"); } }
    public string Month { get { return Date.ToString("MMMM"); } }
    public string Day { get { return Date.ToString("dd"); } }
    public string Weekday { get { return Date.ToString("dddd"); } }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        // data
        var _Data = Enumerable.Range(1, 20)
            .Select(x => new Datum { Date = DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(x * 14)) });
        Data = new ObservableCollection<Datum>(_Data);
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Datum> Data { get; private set; }
}
```

And then try this XAML:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>

<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid Width="400">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" >
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Right">
                        <Run Text="Search" />
                        <LineBreak />
                        <Run Text="Data" />
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBox Width="100" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"><TextBlock Text="Year" /></Border>
            <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"><TextBlock Text="Month" /></Border>
            <Border Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"><TextBlock Text="Day" /></Border>
            <Border Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1"><TextBlock Text="Weekday" /></Border>
        </Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Width="400">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0" />
                            </Style>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Year}" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Month}" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Day}" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Weekday}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
        <Grid Width="400">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
                <TextBlock Text="Showing 1 to 10 of 371" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

You should get something like this:

[image]

Comment: This example looks exactly like the way I want my table. For me, there is one pronlem though. I Would like to be able to click on the items in the list. If it was a listview I could have used the SelectedItem, but it does not exist in an ItemsControl. Is it possible to achieve this in some way?

Answer (score 2):

To add to Jerry's XAML in his answer. You can replace the ItemsControl with a ListBox (same template/itemTemplate modifications) to get the same view, but also the ability to use SelectedIndex, but I don't know if that applies to this question.

Note: I did find you need to add a Width to the ListBox. You can't just let the Grid in the ItemTemplate do it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for something like this.

**XAML**:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Fill="Black" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" />
    <TextBlock Text="Integer" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="14" />
    <TextBlock Text="String" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="14" />
    <ListView x:Name="ListViewDisplay" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Background="White" RequestedTheme="Light">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Integer}" Margin="5" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="14" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding String}" Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="14" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

**Behind code**:

```
public sealed partial class SamplePage : Page
{
    ObservableCollection<ROWS> r = new ObservableCollection<ROWS>();
    public SamplePage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        r.Add(new ROWS { Integer = 1, String = "ONE" });
        r.Add(new ROWS { Integer = 2, String = "TWO" });
        r.Add(new ROWS { Integer = 3, String = "THREE" });
        r.Add(new ROWS { Integer = 4, String = "FOUR" });
        r.Add(new ROWS { Integer = 5, String = "FIVE" });
        ListViewDisplay.ItemsSource = r;
    }
}

public class ROWS {
    public int Integer { get; set; }
    public string String { get; set; }
}
```

**Result**:

[image: Result]